# Randomly Freezes - How Can I Diagnose the Problem?

Tags: 10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

At random times, Ubuntu 10.04 freezes, and I have to do a hard shutdown.  It was upgraded from 9.10 which didn't freeze.  First, is this is common problem with a quick answer, and if not, what can I do to diagnose it?  I've tried checking application/kernel logs, but nothing gives me a clue as to what caused the problem.  My guess, is that since the OS froze, no logs could be updated.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicates: [I have problems installing ubuntu 10.04](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/i-have-problems-installing-ubuntu-10-04) - [How can I find out what is causing my gnome panel to freeze](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/787/how-can-i-find-out-what-is-causing-my-gnome-panel-to-freeze) - [Occasional excessive iowait freezes computer how to diagnose](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/occasional-excessive-iowait-freezes-computer-how-to-diagnose)