# What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?

Tags: freeze, performance, bug-reporting

All operating systems freeze sometimes, and Ubuntu is no exception. What should I do to regain control when...

- just one program stops responding?
- nothing at all responds to mouse clicks or key presses?
- the mouse stops moving entirely?
- I have an [Intel Bay Trail CPU?](https://ark.intel.com/products/codename/55844/Bay-Trail#@nofilter)

In what order should I try various solutions before deciding to pull the power plug?

What should I do when starting up Ubuntu fails?  Is there a diagnostic procedure I can follow?

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [How to fix non-responsive Ubuntu system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39846/how-to-fix-non-responsive-ubuntu-system)

Comment: Related: [Diagnosing and fixing apparently random Ubuntu crashes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/742278/78223)

Comment: You should meditate and start learning Windows or MacOS! far more stable than linux.

Comment: Those are 2 different issues - the freeze, and failure to boot.

Answer (score 487, accepted):

### When a single program stops working:

When a program window stops responding, you can usually stop it by clicking the X-shaped close button at the top left of the window. That will generally result in a dialog box saying that the program is not responding (but you already knew that) and presenting you with the option to kill the program or to continue to wait for it to respond.

Sometimes this does not work as expected. If you can't close a window by normal means, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `xkill`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your mouse cursor will then turn into an **X**. Hover over the offending window and left-click to kill it. Right clicking will cancel and return your mouse to normal.

If your program is running from a terminal, on the other hand, you can usually halt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. If not, [find the name and process ID of its command](https://askubuntu.com/q/180336/), and tell the program to end as soon as possible with `kill [process ID here]`. It sends the default signal `SIGTERM` (`15`). If all else fails, as a last resort send `SIGKILL` (`9`): `kill -9 [process ID here]`. Note that you should only use `SIGKILL` as a last resort, because the process will be terminated immediately by the kernel with no opportunity for cleanup. It does not even get the signal - it just stops to exist.

(Killing a process by `kill -9` allways works if you have the permission to kill. In some special cases the process is still listed by `ps` or `top` (as "zombie") - in this case, the program was killed, but the process table entry is kept, becuse it's needed later.)

### When the mouse stops working:

If the keyboard still works, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gnome-terminal` (or, if these fail to launch, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login with your *username* and *password*). From there you can troubleshoot things. I'm not going to get into mouse troubleshooting here, as I haven't researched it. If you just want to try restarting the GUI, run `sudo service lightdm restart`. This should bring down the GUI, which will then attempt to respawn, bringing you back to the login screen.

### When you have an Intel Bay Trail CPU

See https://askubuntu.com/a/803649/225694.

### When everything, keys and mouse and all, stop working:

First try the Magic SysReq method outlined in [Phoenix' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/6969). If that doesn't work, press the **Reset** button on the computer case. If even that doesn't work, you'll just have to *power-cycle* the machine.
***May you never reach this point.***

Comment: I've recently discovered that, rather than the "ps $options | grep $process_name" referenced above, one can just enter "pgrep $process_name" to achieve approximately the same result (for certain values of $options).

Comment: @Chan-Ho Suh Not being able to start up isn't really "freezing". We cover failure to boot in http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it. Or do you mean freezing on login?

Comment: One should never recommend `kill -9` right off the bat. Once should instead attempt to kill the process with less drastic signals first, and only use -9 if all else fails.

Comment: Why REISUB is useful when the system freezed? I can't find which option in REISUB can get control back to my own except reboot. Thank you~

Comment: `sudo service lightdm restart`: Not awesome - will kill all gui processes in Ubuntu 13.04 at least - for me that included running Virtual Machines etc :(

Comment: In case of temporary hangs when the storge media is being used constantly especially if it is slow (flash card / stick) you can try reducing the memory allocated to dirty bytes to about 4 MB. In /etc/sysctl.conf write vm_dirty_bytes = 4194304 and vm.dirty_background_bytes = 1048576 also reduce waiting time to 3 seconds vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 300 and vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 300 (increasing the buffer makes the freezes longer and less frequent !)

Comment: @sam the `S` and `U` in `REISUB` take care that the harddisk write operations get finished before reboot, to avoid inconsistent, half-written data. The harddisk writes could take very long in the case that the system is "almost hanging" in some lowlevel way.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Very true - but the Answer says to first try `kill` without giving  signal. That will use the default signal `SGTERM`, which is the right one to try before `SIGKILL`, I think.

Comment: For a command not running in a terminal, no need to try `SIGHUP`,  it's saying the connection dropped ("hangup"), like when you see `CARRIER LOST` on a dialin modem connection. (Some daemons reread configuration `SIGHUP`.) The default signal, `SIGTEM` is telling the program "terminate as soon as possible" - so it can do important cleanup before.  `SIGKILL` does not tell the programm anything - it tells the kernel "delete that program" - so it just stops to exist. It will just never get a next CPU cycle. So it can not do any, because it never finds out that it will stop to exist. (I'll edit.)

Comment: "May you never reach this point." In most Linuxes, this is the only point reached. I have never seen a Linux freeze that can be fixed.

Comment: I must say this Alt+F2, type xkill was a crazy thing i didn't knew, totally saved the day

Comment: Go out of your house and turn the power board switch off, works every time ;)

Comment: and: "When only the keyboard stop working, the task bar and the current window stop responding?

Answer (score 626):

If it locks up completely, you can REISUB it, which is a safer alternative to just cold rebooting the computer.

REISUB by:

While holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the <kbd>SysReq (Print Screen)</kbd> keys, type <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

```
R:  Switch to XLATE mode
E:  Send Terminate signal to all processes except for init
I:  Send Kill signal to all processes except for init
S:  Sync all mounted file-systems
U:  Remount file-systems as read-only
B:  Reboot
```

Some mnemonics for REISUB:

- Rise up (from the dead) if you're inclined to zombie movies
- **BUSIER** backwards, as in *The System is **busier** than it should be!*
- **R**eboot **E**ven **I**f **S**ystem **U**tterly **B**roken.
- Or the classic: **R**aising **E**lephants **I**s **S**o **U**tterly **B**oring

This is the SysReq key:

[image: SysReq key]

**NOTE:** There exists a less radical way than rebooting the whole system. If <kbd>SysReq</kbd> key works, you can kill processes one-by-one using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Kernel will kill the mostly «expensive» process each time. If you want to kill all processes for one console, you can issue <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

**NOTE:** You should explicitly enable these key combinations. Ubuntu ships with sysrq default setting 176 (128+32+16), which allows to run only **SUB** part of REISUB combination. You can change it to 1 (all commands enabled) or 244 which is potentially less harmful. To do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf
```

and switch 176 to 244; then

```
echo 244 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

It will immediately work! You can test this by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. For me, it killed the active browser tab, then all extensions. And if you will continue, you can reach X Server restart.

---

More info on all the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd> functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

Comment: In the event you're forced to do this, do it slowly. Let a few seconds pass in between each keypress so that the commands you're invoking have a chance to finish before you go to the next one.

Comment: In case you like mnemonics: Raising Elephants Is So Utterly Boring, or Reboot Event If System Utterly Broken. I've also seen it as RSEIUB (Raising Skinny Elephants is Utterly Boring).

Comment: I actually came up with this one and try to remember it this way: "Reset System Environment In UBuntu". or "Reset Environment In System UBuntu".

Comment: What do you do if you're using a Mac that has no SysRq key?

Comment: @Cerin [How do I use REISUB with an Apple slim aluminum keyboard?](http://askubuntu.com/q/4401/1859)

Comment: What if I have a keyboard without `SysRq`, and `Print Screen`? In my Italian keyboard there is none of those. I have `Stamp`, `Bloc Scorr`, `Pausa/Interr`.

Comment: @Bakuriu it should be [`Stamp`](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_print_screen_key_called_on_Italian_Keyboard).

Comment: Does this work only when it freezes?! I just tried to test if it works by pressing Alt+Fn+SysReq (Dell laptop keyboard) but did not work!

Comment: Thankfully, Alt Gr works as well according to the Wikipedia article. Otherwise it would be quite an exercise to type while simultaneously pressing Alt (on the left side) and SysRq (on the right side).

Btw from the wiki article again: "Under graphical environments (such as GNOME or KDE) 'Alt'+'PrintScrn/SysRq'+key combination generally only leads to a screenshot being dumped. To avoid this Print Screen feature the magic SysRq combination should include the Ctrl, becoming 'Ctrl'+'Alt'+'SysRq'+key."

Comment: BTW, Magic-SysRq appears to not work out of the box at least in Kubuntu 14.04 LiveCD: I get "This sysrq operation is disabled" on any Magic-SysRq command. One has to enable it by `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`. But it does on the installed Kubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Ruslan I added some information on how to setup desired keys to be enabled.

Comment: Is it recommended to restore from a backup after doing this?

Comment: Does this rely on how the keyboard is connected to the box ? PS2 , USB,  bluetooth, or 2.4G?

Comment: I normally remember that it's BUSIER backwards but, I don't know what each letter does. What about: Raw Execution Insist Sync Umount Bang!

Comment: Why the REI part is not enabled by default? I found that part more useful than the SUB part..

Comment: Can I use this to always kill Chrome? It's always Chrome that causes my crash..

Comment: Can anyone tell me what _SysRq_ is on Lenovo T series keyboars? The Print/Screenshot key (the one between _AltGr_ and _Right Ctrl_ has no effect.

Comment: Is there a good reason this is not enabled by default? I wonder if I perhaps should not enable it..

Comment: I dont have that key SysReq

Comment: As the Wikipedia article mention this was relevant _before the advent of journaled filesystems_. Could also be mentioned that the `echo..` command is just to apply the change for the current session, same as `sudo sysctl kernel.sysrq=244`

Answer (score 64):

You can make the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> open the *System Monitor*, with which you can kill any unresponsive applications.

1. Open up *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Keyboard Shortcuts* and click *Add*.
   In the *Command* field, enter `gnome-system-monitor`. Name the shortcut whatever you want.

[image]

2. Click *Apply* and then click where it says *Disabled*. Now hit the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

[image]

3. Close *Keyboard Shortcuts* and try out the shortcut:

[image]

Comment: but if X is locking up fully, or even the kernel is hung, you can't do much with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Unfortunately, System Monitor is quite CPU intensive. It typically consumes up to 20% of my CPU, so if you're computer's bogged down, launching SM is only going to grind it into the dirt faster.

Comment: If you can open System Monitor you can get to a terminal, in which case your OS is not frozen.

Comment: System Monitor is, unfortunately, not the trusty Task Manager on Windows. As commented above, it will only launch if (ironically) Ubuntu isn't frozen. And even if it does, it's unresponsive anyway.

Comment: An alternative is to open a terminal and use `top` from there. Less resource intensive.

Comment: This is where to enable `Ctrl + Alt + Backspace` to restart X server in KDE Plasma https://forum.endeavouros.com/uploads/default/original/3X/4/1/4146cfde3dca58a8bfba621ebbab0122bbebcd6b.png

Answer (score 48):

Freezes such as you have described can be both software and hardware related and as you have found sometimes frustratingly difficult to diagnose.

### Hardware

If this is a desktop PC look at your hardware-cards. For both laptops and desktops possibly acpi type issues.

It might be useful to temporarily simplify your configuration to have just the graphics card connected with a standard keyboard and mouse.  All other cards should be removed.

For acpi related issues, try booting with `noapic nomodeset` in your grub boot option.  Its also worth trying `acpi=off` although this could have other undesirable effects such as constant fan usage.

Also worth checking the bios version level and seeing if the vendor has a newer bios version.  The readme notes should hopefully reveal if any newer version fixed crashes and freezes.

### Software

I note you have tried the standard 270 drivers but have failed due to freezes.  Can you clarify if you had similar issues with the open-source driver?  Obviously you will not get Unity during testing this.

Graphics freezing can be one of/or a combination of the driver/compiz/X/kernel

If you are willing to try any of the suggestions below **first** backup your system with a good backup tool such as CloneZilla. You  will need an external media device to receive the image such as a large USB stick/drive or separate internal hard-drive.

## Installing newer nVidia driver

Deactivate (uninstall) your current 173-nvidia driver using the Additional Drivers window.

There are a small number of important fixes primarily in the 275 stable but a small number also in the 280beta that fixed freezes - it is worth a shot to see if these apply to your graphics card. Unfortunately nvidia dont go into detail on which cards they specifically fix (readme.txt)

However - I would strongly recommend a backup unless you feel confident on reversing a nvidia install - especially since you had serious issues with the slightly older 270 drivers. I've used clonezilla countless times and it has always got me out of trouble. You do need a large external drive though - USB stick/external drive or a separate drive.

**X Updates**

The latest graphics drivers have been packaged in the [x updates ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates?field.series_filter=natty).

Note - this will lead you away from the standard baseline - if upgrading in the future `ppa-purge` the PPA itself before upgrading.

You can also manually install the drivers from nVidia:

Try installing the latest nvidia stable 275 or 280 drivers - 
[32bit 280 drivers: ftp site](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/280.04/) and [64bit: 280 drivers: ftp site](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/280.04/)

**To Install**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to TTY1 and login

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

To stop the X server

```
sudo su
```

To run as root

```
cd ~/Downloads
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-280.04.run
```

To install the 32bit driver (equiv for 64bit) then reboot.

**To uninstall**

```
sudo sh NVIDIA* --uninstall
```

Also remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

### X/Kernel/Compiz

If you run classic Ubuntu with effects do you get the same freeze issues as standard Ubuntu?  If you cannot reproduce the freeze with classic Ubuntu (no effects) then this will point you towards a compiz issue.  I would raise a launchpad bug report with the compiz team.

If space is available (e.g. 20Gb), you could dual boot/install alongside the latest oneiric alpha.  Obviously this will itself be unstable, but it will come with the latest X and Kernel. You may need to also install manually the beta 280 graphics drivers above since it probably will not be offered in the Additional Drivers window.

If during testing you dont see the same freeze activity you could try uplifting your X version with the [x-edgers ppa](https://edge.launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) and using kernel kernel 3.0 in Natty.  Going this route is not really desirable - and could cause you upgrade issues in the future - and may have other unforeseen stability issue.  Again, use `ppa-purge` to remove the PPA.

Kernel 3.0 is packaged with the PPA - you'll need to install the headers as well as the kernel itself from synaptic BEFORE rebooting if you intend to install the nvidia drive later.

**This is a testing ppa** - do have a ready backup if you want to try this route.

Comment: ... Are you sure this is a good idea, and that it might solve the problem? Or is this just a guess? As I had a lot of trouble with nvidia-current and nothing worked... That's why I switched to the nvidia-173 one. Can I simply restore my whole system from a CloneZilla back-up? The problem is that I haven't got a spare hard drive anymore to put a system copy on...

Comment: I'll try... Though I haven't got a hard drive to make a back-up to, so I'll just hope it doesn't break my whole system. About feeling uncomfortable using beta software: I'm working on Ubuntu 11.10 Alpha 3 at the moment xD But for work I just use Ubuntu 11.04 as I don't need constant bugs and sometimes crashes while making a website or something similar :p

Comment: Oh dear xD I installed the NVidia-275 driver, and rebooted. X didn't start anymore. No problem, after looking into the log files I saw that another driver was already using the device. I added nouveau to the modprobe blacklist, rebooted, and X started again... But now I've got another problem... I get to see the Unity interface, and then everything simply freezes :p I can switch to the tty's and run commands and everything, but it just seems Unity and the window manager/decorator have crashed. I can't switch back to Gnome Panel (and honestly, I wouldn't want to), ...

Comment: ... as I killed it a few weeks ago (on purpose, as it ran together with the Unity Panel for some strange reason :p). And don't tell me to go using Unity 2D please cause it doesn't work too well and easy for me. In fact, Unity is the only reason I still install non-open source drivers. So please help me? xD

Comment: ... I already did that, except for re-enabling nouveau as I don't see the use of that. But I meant help me out with the freezing problem please.

Answer (score 38):

If you're getting a lot of freezes, there *might* be something wrong with your hardware. I used to get hard lockups every 48 hours due to some less than optimal RAM. Memtest86+ showed the fault after 40 minutes of testing. Swapped the RAM out for some more (under warranty) and I'm now at 32 days, 1 hour of uptime.

Ubuntu doesn't tend to leak its guts all over your memory like Windows can over time. Even if one application or a poor X video driver does, you can restart LigthtDM very simply and just keep going and going and going. I've actually been through three beta versions of the nvidia driver in this one boot :)

Anyway... While knowing how to restart softly is a very handy thing, finding, reporting and fixing the system should be your next priority. If it's an always-on system, you should easily be able to make it between kernel updates* without needing a restart.

*You *should* restart when you get kernel updates as they'll be security fixes that won't be applied until you reboot into the newer kernel.

Comment: I agree that RAM is usually the culprit for unstable systems. I had a problem once that Memtest86+ was not able to found but I could trigger it repeatedly in 5 minutes running sha1sums on very big files repeatedly (checksums changed every now and then). It, too, was fixed by changing memory sticks. Other common causes are unstable power source or poor capasitors on the motherboard. The only way to diagnose these issues is to keep swapping parts until it works.

Comment: +1 for memtest86. RAM can be faulty without you really noticing it in daily use.

Answer (score 37):

When everything stops working, first try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to go to a terminal, where you can likely kill X or other problem processes.

If even that doesn't work, try using holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysReq</kbd> while pressing (slowly, with a few seconds between each) <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>.

This puts the keyboard in raw mode, ends tasks in various states, syncs the disks, etc, and finally reboots the machine. 
You will get much better results doing this than just pulling the plug. Of course, if this fails, you're pretty much left with pulling the plug.

Comment: A way to remember "REISUB" is "Reboot Even If System Utterly Broken".

Comment: or "Raising Elephants Is So Utterly Boring" :P

Comment: I remember it using "BUSIER" Backwards

Comment: Between `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` and trying to kill processes, and `Alt`+`SysRq`+`R` `E` `I` `S` `U` `B`, it's worth pressying `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete`. If you successfully got to a text-based virtual console (from having pressed `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`), this will virtually always reboot the machine.

Comment: Much blunter and in Spanish: REInicia SUBnormal

Comment: Holy shit. REISUB can't be ignored hahah

Answer (score 33):

Also, sometimes it's simply the X-Server which hangs - a case I've most often found when you're using Compiz.

If this is the case you can kill X, which will restart and drop you back at the log-in screen.

The default sequence is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Although this is turned off by default (presumably new-users were accidentally hitting it) and can be turned back on like this:

1. `System` → `Keyboard` (i.e. the Keyboard Preferences Dialogue)
2. *Layouts* tab
3. Click the *Options* button
4. At the *Key Sequence to kill the X server* point check *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>*.

Comment: If your video driver is using kernel modesetting (KMS), it's unlikely this will be sufficient to fix lockups, you have to use sysrq or power cycle.  (Go ahead and try C-A-B, it obviously can't hurt; it does work when an app (like compiz/unity) is stuck, rather than X itself, however other answers on this page would be better in this case).  But when it doesn't work, now you know why.  :-)

Comment: A note for new users about KMS: As a general rule, if you're using a binary driver (probably if you have an nVidia graphics card, and sometimes if you've got an ATI card) you're video driver is not using KMS.

Comment: I can't find this in Ubuntu 14.04. When I go to Settings > Keyboard the tabs are only Typing and Shortcuts. I just looked through all the shortcuts and couldn't find "Key sequence to kill the X server". Can I still do this on 14.04?

Answer (score 30):

My first favourite when total freeze occured - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

That combo kills X, and returns me to the graphical login screen. If that doesn't work, try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 19):

What I do is opening a terminal with eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Login and use the terminal to kill the process that is lagging

```
ps -e | grep <procesname>
```

This shows the *processID* of the process with that name

```
(sudo) kill <processID>
```

This shuts down the process safely, in case that doesn't work use

```
(sudo) kill -9 <processID>
```

Use the man pages for more information about these commands.

You can get back to the graphical user interface with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: `ps` and `grep PROCESS` can be replaced by a `pgrep PROCESS` call, and your whole thing can simply be replaced by `pkill PROCESS` or a `killall PROCESS`.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that. Seems to be UNIX commands too, nice

Comment: However, the default behavior of `pgrep` is not to show anything but the process ID itself. If you want to know the process's full name and any other information, `ps` is still a very valuable tool.

Answer (score 19):

DoR and Phoenix has answered this well. To make this page more complete I would add:

**If it is only X that is "broken", than you can use kernel to kill it:**

<kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

For laptops (depends on the model, typically needed if "SysRq" is written in blue):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (release <kbd>Fn</kbd> after pressing <kbd>SysRq</kbd>).

Comment: FWIW it depends on the laptop -- on my ThinkPad Alt+SysRq doesn't require Fn nor Ctrl.

Comment: The key pressing sequence is neatly described here (Ubuntu Forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11773367#post11773367), particulary for laptop where 'Fn' key makes a difference. I had to follow it on my Lenovo Ideapad - hold 'Fn' with left hand first, press Alt + SysRq in right, leave 'Fn' and continue with REISUB slowly.

Answer (score 19):

In such cases you can try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console. Then login with your password.

### Restarting the GUI

You can try to restart your graphical desktop with:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If you're running Ubuntu 11.04 *or earlier*, you should use this instead (as `gdm` used to be the default display manager):

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

If you're using Kubuntu instead, then the default display manager is `kdm`, so you should instead use:

```
sudo service kdm restart
```

If you're using  another display manager, replace `ligthdm`/`gdm`/`kdm` with its name.

### Restarting the Machine

If you want to do a clean system reboot, use:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 15):

To diagnose the freezes you should be able to use the net console (or serial serial console for that matter). Follow the set up instructions outlined [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole).

Comment: I'll give that a shot and post-back the results.

Comment: This worked like a champ.  Identified the problem as my graphics card: "radeon .... reserve failed for wait".  Now I know what to look for.

Answer (score 15):

The first thing to look at is if it is just X that's frozen, or the whole system.  Enable ssh and then ssh into the system.  If you can't ssh into it, then it's probably a kernel lock up.  If you *can* ssh in, then it might be just a gpu lockup.

Next try restarting X. Do this by restarting the display manager:

- On Ubuntu 11.10 and later, LightDM is the display manager, so run:

  ```
  service lightdm restart
  ```
- On Ubuntu 11.04 and earlier, GDM is the display manager, so run:

  ```
  service gdm restart
  ```

If that works, then it's perhaps an X bug.  If it still doesn't work, then you may have a GPU lockup in the kernel drm driver.  It would be useful to know at this point whether you're running the -ati (open source) driver, or -fglrx (closed source) driver.

Comment: Thanks! My desktop randomly freezes as well. Running 'service gdm restart' always brings it up. Most of the times the desktop seems to freeze when Firefox is running. Any ideas on how I can debug/fix this ?

Comment: Well, generally when I find myself using the word 'random' in describing a bug, I take that as a clue that I need to do a bit more to better characterize the bug.  E.g., how often does it happen, are there any things that seem more likely to trigger it than others, if any other symptoms occur in conjunction, etc.

Comment: You should also consider your hardware and driver.  Some drivers like -intel are more likely to have freeze bugs than other drivers like -ati.  Hardware also can play a factor, such as if you put a high end ATI card into a box with a sketchy power supply.  Bad RAM, buggy motherboards, overheating, power irregularities, etc. all can result in freezes.

Comment: Looking through the other commenters on this page, you can see suggestions all over the map.  Freezes are an unfortunately common end result of a whole variety of different kinds of problems.  They can be software, hardware, or a combination of the two.  This is why it is extremely important that the original reporter provide as detailed and thorough a report as possible.  This is also why two people both experiencing similar freezes really have to be treated as completely separate bugs, unless their HW and SW are exactly the same.

Comment: Freezes on different drivers are debugged in different ways.  For instance, -intel has a set of debugging tools you can install that allow you to capture GPU dumps.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze for details.

Answer (score 13):

If you ever use the magic `SysRq` key as suggested in the first answer, just try getting the keyboard to work first with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>; then try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> again.

It may work and you may save yourself a reboot. Only if it doesn't work you should try the whole *REISUB* sequence.

Answer (score 12):

If you have to do a hard shutdown I'd be wondering if the memory (RAM) was failing. On your next boot, try running memtest86. To do this:

- while booting, hold down a shift key
- the GRUB menu will appear
- use the cursor keys to select the last option "memtest86"
- press enter

You'll get a basic display and it will try reading and writing lots of values to all of your RAM. As long as there are no failures, you'll see a green status. If there is any failure it will turn red. In that case you'll need to replace at least one stick of your RAM.

There is also [community documentation of diagnosing hardware failures](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FaultyHardware).

Answer (score 11):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> on your keyboard to open TTY1. When it opens, run the [kill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command. An example is below.

First you use [ps](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps).

This will show you all processes running (`ps | less` if you want to see the results page by page). 
Then you look for the PID of the process you want to terminate.
After this use: `kill pid`

> kill command- Stop a process from running
>
> Syntax: kill [-s sigspec] [-n signum] [-sigspec] jobspec or pid kill -l [exit_status]
>
> Description:  Most modern shells, Bash included, have a built-in kill
> function. In Bash, both signal names and numbers are
>
> > accepted as options, and arguments may be job or process IDs. An exit
> > status can be reported using the -l option: zero when at least one
> > signal was successfully sent, non-zero if an error occurred. Using the
> > kill command from /usr/bin, your system might enable extra options,
> > such as the ability to kill processes from other than your own user ID
> > and specifying processes by name, like with pgrep and pkill. Both kill
> > commands send the TERM signal if none is given.

Extra: [Use Ctrl+Alt+Del for Task Manager in Linux to Kill Tasks Easily](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20355/use-ctrlaltdel-for-task-manager-in-linux-to-kill-tasks-easily/)

Comment: How about if I am not sure about pid which is causing my system to freeze. There could be many processes running interfering with each other making the system freeze. Could you please explain how to tackle in such case..

Comment: Using the top command on the console you can often see which process is hanging, by checking the cpu % column. You can then kill that process.

Comment: What command? ps

Comment: i meant the command 'top' from the console.

Comment: As of kinetic 22.10 I had to use CTRL-ALT-F3 to get to terminal. ALT-F2 to return to GUI. Ctrl-Alt-F1 just locked my session.

Answer (score 8):

I thinks there is no such thing as a perfect distro, even in Windows they have this screen of death.

- Open another terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Login with your username and password.
- Issue this command:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
  ```

  *This restarts or logs you out of your current session but it will not reboot.*

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> go get back to your graphical interface.

Answer (score 7):

You can always do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and write `killall <program>` or `xkill` and click on the window you want smashed!

Answer (score 7):

(Community wiki answer - solution was originally buried in the [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/1246/j0rd4n) [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2301/randomly-freezes-how-can-i-diagnose-the-problem#question))

**SOLUTION:**

Solved it.

My particular problem was my graphics card (integrated Radeon 9000 series).  netconsole revealed I was getting the error: `"reserve failed for wait"`.  After trial-and-error, I manually configured my video card and disabled hardware acceleration. Completely fixed the issue.

Here is what I did:

*Manually Created xorg.conf*

Ubuntu automatically configures xorg.conf and doesn't use a file.  To edit this file, you have to tell Ubuntu to explicitly create one and then edit it.  Here are the steps:

1. Restart system
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> as GRUB boots
3. Select root terminal in GRUB login menu
4. Execute: `X -config xorg.conf.new`
5. Copy: `cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

*Disable Hardware Acceleration*

The following is specific to my Radeon card, but I'm sure other cards have a similar setup.

1. Edit `xorg.conf`
2. Find "Device" section for graphics card
3. Uncomment "NoAccel" option and set to "True"
4. Save + reboot

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Some other resources:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen

Answer (score 5):

You might get some extra information when you switch to the TTY view. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get this, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (or maybe <kbd>F8</kbd>) to get back to the GUI. You can have different sessions on most of the F-keys but that's different question altogether.

Comment: I tried that but the entire system is locked.  Keyboard is completely unresponsive.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to add the *"Force Quit"* applet to your Gnome top panel and when a program doesn't respond, click on the force quit and then on the application.

I am surprised with so many answers, this isn't mentioned. Of course, you can always do a `ps -A` and pipe that to `grep` for your program name. And `kill -9` that. I prefer simplicity.

Comment: That's not an option on Unity or GNOME 3 anymore, is it?

Answer (score 5):

My ubuntu is super prone to freezing (probably 20 odd times a day).
I use the magic sysrq key too, but instead of using it to reboot or kill xserver, 
I use the 'f' command which calls oom_kill, effectively dropping a process.
I've only ever seen this drop chrome tabs (as I tend to have quite a few heavyweight
ones open at a time).  Anyway, this get's me out of this mess 95% of the time.

So when my ubuntu freezes (locks up, mouse stops responding etc), I hold <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>sysrq</kbd> and then hit <kbd>f</kbd> (if you don't do this correctly it will take a screenshot instead).  I usually have to repeat this combo a couple of times before ubuntu spurs back to life.

I'd have given up on ubuntu a long time ago if I hadn't discovered this, hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run a command. Type `xkill` and hit Enter.

Your mouse cursor will transform into a cross that can force to close any window you click on.

*If somebody can provide a screenshot, I think that would be useful.*

Comment: not working since the desktop is frozen

Answer (score 4):

There were some missed bugs between the relation of Unity/Compiz, the X.org system and the Video driver. These bugs of course are dealt with with newer, updated versions of Unit, Compiz, X or the video Driver.

When inside Unity and everything is slow and basically damaged, to go to TTY1, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. When in the terminal, type your user and password to get to the prompt line. You can also get to the TTY when booting by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, then on the GRUB menu, selecting recovery mode.

1. Install Xorg Edgers PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Depending on your video card you can either install the 304 series, 310 Series, 313 Series or any newer one that appears there. I recommend always test the latest version and only if it throws a problem, then go down from there until you reach a version where everything works correctly. For example, if you have a GT 9500 or later (Like in my case to which I also have a 440 GT, 560 TI and 680 GTX) the only version that solves all my problems is the 313.18 that came out a couple of days ago. So I would do this:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-313
   ```

   This would install the latest version of the 313 series. It fixes MANY video problems with compiz, unity and xorg. The 310 series also fixes many issues but have not tested that one with my video cards. The other Nvidia versions are nvidia-experimental-304 and nvidia-experimental-310 as of this writing.
2. Reboot to test if your video card not works correctly with Ubuntu. If you get any problems regarding Nvidia config file, simply open a terminal and type `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and reboot.

There are other nice questions that could also help like:

[How can I update my NVIDIA driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46436/how-can-i-update-my-nvidia-driver)

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/newest-nvidia-card-what-driver-should-i-install/61433#61433)

[Can not install Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147576/cant-install-gtx-680-drivers-on-12-04/194628#194628)

[What's the difference between the nvidia-current, and nvidia-current-updates packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66548/whats-the-difference-between-the-nvidia-current-and-nvidia-current-updates-pac)

Or even one that is more generic: [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d)

Answer (score 4):

To debug the freeze, you can use [Magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), for example:

<sup>Note: Consider holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>  (depending on your keyboard).</sup>

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> (no <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>) - Set the console log level to 9 to show more of kernel messages
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> - Display list of blocked (D state) tasks
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> - Shows a stack backtrace for all active CPUs.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> - Output a list of current tasks and their information to the console
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> - Output the current registers and flags to the console
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> - Display all active high-resolution timers and clock sources.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> - Output current memory information to the console

Other things to try during freeze:

<sup>Note: Consider holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> (depending on your keyboard).</sup>

- Reset the nice level of all high-priority and real-time tasks by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>.
- Try forcing a return to a text console try hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> (from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>).
- Kill all processes on the current virtual console (can kill X) by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>.
- Perform a system crash (if it is configured) by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

If nothing works, you should perform [a safe reboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses) by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>**REISUB**</kbd>, which is:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>: Un**R**aw (take control of keyboard back from X).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>: t**E**rminate (send [SIGTERM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTERM) to all processes).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>: k**I**ll (send [SIGKILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGKILL) to all processes, forcing them to terminate immediately).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>: **S**ync all mounted filesystems (flush data to disk).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>: **U**nmount (remount all filesystems in read-only mode),
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>SysRq</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>: immediately re**B**oot the system.

  <sup>Note: If above hard reboot combination won't work, the freeze could be caused by defected hardware, not video drivers.</sup>

If you can't use *Magic SysRq key*, see also: [Diagnosing and fixing apparently random Ubuntu crashes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/742278/78223)

After reboot, check your `kern.log` for details, especially call traces generated by above kernel commands. This can help to find the right bug report for it, and find the solution. Check the following [`kern.log` example](https://gist.github.com/kenorb/5b95caa1694dbf7f030ccc808a110856).

You can check the latest crash log by:

```
journalctl -b -1 # Then hit Shift-G to jump to the end.
```

To list other journal logs, run:

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

Suggested solution:

- Upgrade your Ubuntu and kernel to the latest version.
- If problem repeats, the workaround is to install [NVIDIA drivers](https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/78223), which replaces Nouveau video driver.

See also:

- [Ubuntu desktop hangs occasionally during regular use](https://askubuntu.com/q/874307/78223)
- [How to fix non-responsive Ubuntu system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39846/21471).

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar issues with 10.04.  X would hang and and nothing but a reset would fix it.  I updated my nvidia drivers to the latest version and I haven't had issues since.

Comment: Using ATI video drivers...but it might be worth looking into.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Replace with the latest Linux kernel 2.6.35 or up that will solve your problem.  Follow these steps from this [link](http://www.ramoonus.nl/2010/05/linux-kernel-2-6-34-installation-guide-for-ubuntu-linux-10-04/).

Comment: Ah!  I'll give it a shot.  The guide posted is for 2.6.34 but you said I needed to install 2.6.35.  Which one should I do?

Comment: Bummer.  Looks like I already have it installed.  uname -r reveals 2.6.35-24-generic

Answer (score 3):

if possible, try to open an ssh shell from another computer. this is an option If you knew in advance that the computer might hang soon, open the connection first before you perform that task.

I do this sometimes when I know vmware runs crazy and the GUI of ubuntu (the vmware host) becomes unresponsive. I can do a suspend from the ssh shell, it might take a while until it gets thru, and after a while the computer is idle again.

Comment: A better idea would going to an other TTY (non-GUI) by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F[1-6] where `F[1-6]` is F1, F2, ..., F6. This is especially helpful if your network connection is heavily used. (to switch back, use Ctrl + Alt + F7. Replace F7 by F8 if it didn't work.

Comment: Sure, however I always tend to forget these key combinations. And when I know I have to carry  out some tasks/experiments where the computer might hang, it's always handy to have access to a second computer available right next to the hanging one.

Comment: For some experiments, a virtual machine in VirtualBox is recommended. In that way, you can easily revert the machines state.

Answer (score 3):

### In the very specific case you are using Virtualbox to run a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit  (Ubuntu) host using VT-x or AMD-V (hardware virtualization technology built-in your CPU) only

Virtualbox may make your 32-bit host randomly crash when you run a 64-bit guest on it using VT-x or AMD-V (hardware virtualization technology built-in your CPU). It is a [known issue](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html).

#### 2 solutions:

1. You have to run 32-bit guests only on your current 32-bit host [recommended if you have less than 2 GB of RAM];
2. You have to switch to Ubuntu 64-bit as host (you can even perform a 32-bit to 64-bit "migration" by reinstalling Ubuntu 64-bit without touching to your "/home" folder) [recommended if you have 2 GB of RAM or more].

Please note that you can run 64-bit and 32-bit guests on a 64-bit host using Virtualbox without any problem.

Other answers have very well covered general cases...

Answer (score 3):

If you have tried all of the above and the freezing problem remains, you might want to try what I did.

Apply generous amounts of contact cleaner to CPU, RAM and any other chip complex enough to show those tiny, tightly packed pins. They can lose conductivity from dust accumulation as well as shorting due to humidity.

Some days after the cleaning (I used CRC 2-26) and a series of really brutal stress tests, my PC hasn't frozen once.

So, for all of you getting sudden unexpected freezings, give up messing around with your OS beyond what's reasonable and do an exhaustive dust and contact cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the culprit in my case was plain and simple overheating. I live in a warmer climate and if I am not running airconditioning my laptop starts locking up. Pointing a fan directly at it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions I found that stopped my computer from freezing was to stop the  cpu scheduler setting itself to ondemand. This is found in the `/etc/init.d/ondemand` script.

I just renamed the file.

```
sudo mv /etc/init.d/ondemand /etc/init.d/ondemand.bk
```

This breaks all the symbolic links to ondemand. So it won't start up at boot time. This will put some error messages into your log.

A better way is to use update-rc.d. I was lasy and have not tried these commands.

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove
```

Or:

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand stop 2 3 4 5 S
```

To start it again:

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand Start 2 3 4 5 S
```

Although starting it again caused my computer to free again. So I left it disabled.

Comment: And how do I get it back afterward with the "better way"?

Comment: @Robinj I did not start it again as it kept causing my computer to freeze. But you could use the update-rc.d command to update the links again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Ctrl+alt+t to get the terminal, then find the hanging process (ps -ef | grep ) then kill it using pid found (kill -9 )
2. Press Ctrl+alt+F2 (in some cases fn key also to be pressed) to enter single user mode.
   Login and restart lightdm/kdm service

sudo service start lightdm.

3. Graceful reset press alt+print screen+r+e+i+s+u+b
4. If still issue, then power off button is last resort :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom built PC keep freezing on me.  I put the temperature sensors in the gnome panel and was able to see if the CPU, HDD, Motherboard (basically any system temp) were getting hot at the time of the lock.

Your ATI card might be running hot and you need increased airflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using motherboard of intel 8xx, then I would strongly recommend to migrate to **Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat**, I think they have solved the Xorg related bugs.

I had faced the same problems but once I installed Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat, I have never faced any Xfreeze issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on Lenovo Thinkpad core i5, it kept on freezing completely and I had to manually restart it by power cycle. I solved it by updating my Ubuntu kernel to latest version. It might fix your problem too. Here are the instructions to do that:

1- Go here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
Download 3 (maybe 4) debs to a folder somewhere:

- linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_all.deb
- linux-headers-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
- linux-image-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb
- linux-image-extra-VERSION-NUMBER_amd64.deb   # if available

2- Install the debs with whatever package manager front-end you use (for example, Gdebi), or use these commands:

```
cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Source: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple fix for random freezes happening under Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.5.0-41) on HP DV7, just use unity_2d :

```
sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Replace `user-session=ubuntu` with `user-session=ubuntu-2d`

```
sudo reboot
```

More info on http://cleanstructions.blogspot.fr/2013/10/fix-random-freezes-ubuntu-1204.html

Memtest passed many times and it just happened from one day to the other, possibly after an upgrade. I just couldn't investigate the kernel panic, the whole system was locked and logs (when available) were not displaying anything relevant to me.

Has anyone has an idea about what is wrong with my graphics card for not supporting open GL anymore?

Answer (score 0):

For those who:

- have screen freezes but applications are still working
- and you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
- and you have no other option but to restart (`service lightdm restart` doesn't work)
- and you have too many applications open and don't want to lose your session

Maybe you can:

- go do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
- run `pm-suspend` (will suspend the machine)
- start the machine; 
  you should get the machine back to the state before the screen freezes (at least for me it did)

I've tried all solutions suggested above, but none of them work or part of it worked but I was still forced to restart the machine and lose all running applications.  This is not the best solution but at least I don't lose the applications I need when working.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try the next key combination, please remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings you back.  Remember?  Really?  OK, then: If the Ubuntu GUI doesn't show up or freezes just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a terminal.

You should have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to see this message again.

It is the easiest solution, but not permanent, after that your Ubuntu can continue to  freeze, but you can repeat this process every time, when Ubuntu freezes. :)

Comment: It's not really a solution to the problem: more of a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

In my case `compiz` causes the freezing; I can move mouse cursor, but mouse clicks do nothing. The keyboard works, so, my recipe is restarting `compiz`

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Run this command:

   ```
   killall -9 compiz
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

After suffering with this for over a year I worked around the problem by using Xfce as the desktop environment. I simply installed it using APT: 
    sudo apt-get install xfce4

I have a 2009 PC with in-built graphics and it intermittently had problems every time graphics settings were adjusted (whether via Ubuntu's auto updates or not I'm not sure).

I suppose I could have given Unity 2D a try but Xfce works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the `top` command in the terminal to see the PID of the unresponsive program [Top Function in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcxWA.png)
Then `kill -9 "pid"` without the quotes.

If the nothing at all responds to your click and key strokes or your mouse stops working then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and restart the display manager by running:

```
sudo service lightdm start     # Ubuntu 12.04/14.04
```

or

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target     # Ubuntu 16.04 and later
```

If it fails, don't worry. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will bring you back to your desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the wrong graphics driver was the root of the problem for me.

Using **nouveau**, stopped the freezing, but it was slow.

I realized by using `nvidia-detect` that the graphics driver I should install was nvidia-304 for Geforce GT 8500.

Comment: Please could you restructure your answer to be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop when it freezes, I'm able to do control + alt + fn + f7, then control + alt + fn+ f2. This gets to the shell, then I login with my username and password. To go back to the desktop I do `chvt 8` this gets me back to my current desktop. To find out the active tty's type `w` then chvt to the current one.

That way you can resume your work without rebooting or losing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to power-cycle the machine after installing the candidate kernels from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown. No hardware problems here but beware of such side effects when running on non-stable kernels.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to switch between applications, and not able to use them (for example, unable to change tabs in a browser or scroll) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, just click the log out button and press **Cancel** instead of logging out. This will restore the original unfrozen state.